# mysql - and, like and or combination

Tags: php, mysql

I need somehthing like this:

```
$tags = array('sky', 'earth', 'blue', 'green');  // this varies each time

$st = $db->query("
select id from images where width > 960
and height > 540
and tags like '%" . any of $tags element . "%'");
```

Problem is the last line - how to say it.
Any help?

Comment: Try find_in_set

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$tags = array('sky', 'earth', 'blue', 'green');  // this varies each time
$tag_str="";
foreach($tags as $tag){
$tag_str.=" tags like '%" . $tag . "%' OR ";
}
$tag_str=rtrim($tag_str,"OR ");
$st = $db->query("
select id from images where width > 960
and height > 540
and (".$tag_str.")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
AND tags IN implode('","', $tags)
```

Instead of a like

This will make the $tags array string and put a komma in between.

So the result is:

```
$st = $db->query('
select id from images where width > 960
and height > 540
and tags IN ("' . implode('","', $tags) . '")';
```

Comment: but I need `like any of element` not `like entire string`.

Comment: i adjusted your query for example, this example is any of element

Comment: I see, it seems ok now.

Comment: can you select good answer then, thnx and glad to be of help ;)

Comment: Where did you keep the functionality of the "LIKE" keyword?
he wants to query `LIKE(%sky%)`, while your code yields results querying `LIKE(sky)`... Am I wrong?

Comment: OP said this code was already working for him, a like is not necessary in his case

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$tags = array('sky', 'earth', 'blue', 'green');  // this varies each time

$sql = []; // Stop errors when $words is empty

foreach ($tags as $tag => $value) { 
   $sql[] = 'tags LIKE "%' . $value . '%"';
}

//create SQL string
$sql = 'select id from images where width > 960 and height > 540 and ' .implode(" OR ", $sql);

$st = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: add a space behind  and' .implode